# C on Xcode: bad access

Tags: c, xcode, exc-bad-access

I am trying to finish an assignment for my `C` programming class on `Xcode`. It's simple. It reads a text file, which contains a list of student IDs and their test scores. And then it calculates the overall score based on these data, and writes them to another text file. However, I keep getting this `Bad Access` error message that says:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x7fff00000de4)
```

I don't know what it means. What should I do?

Comment: The code is accessing a memory location it should not. Please post the code if you want people to help.

Comment: This is not enough to help you! Put some break points where u read the file contents & see where it crashes. Post some code for reference

Comment: Put break points to track where it crash and post your crashing code here.

Comment: You should start by googling EXC_BAD_ACCESS; the first hit is http://loufranco.com/blog/understanding-exc_bad_access

Answer (score 5):

The `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` means that you tried to attempt the incorrect address in memory.

You should start with the following:

1. Check that all pointers are initialized before using
2. If you have an array, so possibly you are trying to access the element that  is out of bounds

And of course, use the debugger.